# VBA Excel - Filter selection "wrong" row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to this VBA thing. I just want to ask if why does the selection of my header is in the wrong row? I mean, it should be in `Row 8`, right? But why does it shows in `Row 2`?

[image: Picture]

The header should be in `Row 8` because I have other stuff in `Row 1` to `Row 6`.

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("G1-Q1", "G1-Q2"))
    
        With ws.Cells(8, 3).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter 2, StudID
            .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
            'ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    
Next ws
```

The `ws.Cells(8, 3)` means that it is in `Row 8` and `Column C`, right?

Comment: What does `Debug.Print ws.Cells(8, 3).CurrentRegion.Address` give you?

Comment: @TimWilliams `$B$2:$V$11` and `$B$2:$V$10`

Comment: There's your problem then - `currentregion` needs blank rows/columns bounding your table.

Comment: @TimWilliams what does it mean? Can you explain it further? Sorry, I'm new with this.

Comment: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/currentregion.html

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you very much. I'll study this.

Comment: try change .AutoFilter 2, StudID to .AutoFilter 8, StudID :D

Comment: @Tomasz I tried that yesterday, but it doesn't work.